# Composer always fails to install symfony/var-dumper

Tags: laravel, symfony, composer-php, homestead

I'm trying to install the latest version of Laravel 8 on the latest version of Homestead. When I run `composer install` or `composer update`, installation of symfony/var-dumper always fails:

```
Installing symfony/var-dumper (v5.2.6): Extracting archive
Install of symfony/var-dumper failed

[ErrorException]
file_get_contents(/home/vagrant/code/vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Resources/bin/var-dump-server): 
    Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Despite the error exception, the file `/vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Resources/bin/var-dump-server` does exist.

Things I've tried:

- Deleting the lock file and re-running `composer update`
- Manually specifying specific versions of `var-dumper`, e.g. `composer require symfony/var-dumper:5.2.0`

I always get the same errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a compatibility issue with Composer 2.x. I downgraded to the 1.x channel using `composer self-update --1`, then ran `composer install` again, and the installation succeeded.

Comment: This is wrong. Symfony Var Dumper is certainly not incompatible with Composer 2. A different network issue was made apparent when upgrading to C2, that's all.

Comment: @yivi How can the solution that _I already used to solve the problem_ be "wrong"? I didn't say "Symfony Var Dumper is incompatible with Composer 2", I said there was "a compatibility issue". It could be a compatibility issue between Composer and Homestead, rather than Composer and Symfony. But the core fact that I resolved the issue by downgrading Composer is incontrovertible.

Comment: @yivi Downvoting the question and answer, and flagging for deletion, is getting very carried away.

Comment: I didn’t downvote. I don’t vote when I comment, and viceversa. But it’s still wrong.

Comment: @yivi It's not "wrong" that downgrading Composer resolved the issue. Again, I did not say "Symfony Var Dumper is incompatible with Composer 2"

Answer (score 5):

Remove `/vendor` folder, then run:

`composer update -v`

Comment: `composer install` worked for me as well after removing `vendor` folder

Answer (score 0):

`Composer version 2.2.4 2022-01-08 12:30:42`

and

`symfony/var-dumper  v5.4.3`

is working just fine